# intellij can not resolve 'var' word

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, var, jdbi

I wanna build a little app with `spark framework` and `JDBI` but intellij does not resolve `var` symbol.
Nothing from advises I have already found does not work. I tried to change my language versions, sdks and others from 14 to 15 and vice versa.
The thing that annoy my the most is that two projects (spark and jdbi separately) I made before worked correctly.
Main part of pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Some photos of main settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The error message:
[image]

Comment: BTW: It does not really make sense to configure the compile plugin twice.

Comment: 1. If it works in other projects, there must be a difference. 2. remove the duplicate maven compile configuration 3. could you share the error shown to you?

Comment: sure, the err mess is the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type inference of the `var` keyword can only  be used to declare local variables, e.g. any variable inside a method body or code block.

It's not allowed to declare a class member.

This screenshot shows difference:
[image]

PS: I know that code screenshot shouldn't be used, but in this case I want to make use of the error message and syntax highlighting.